# Recycler view not scrolling to the top after adding new item at the top, as changes to the list adapter has not yet occurred

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I am getting the new list with new item at the start in my live data and then using its data to update the adapter

```
viewModel.myLiveData.observe { this, Observer { myList -> 
        adapter.submitList(myList) 
        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0)
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

`submitList` does its work on a background thread, so there will always be race conditions that delays can't solve.  Fortunately, we can use a `RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver` callback to be informed when the list calculations are complete:

```
yourRecyclerViewAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object: RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onChanged() {
        recycler_view_list.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
    override fun onItemRangeRemoved(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        recycler_view_list.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
    override fun onItemRangeMoved(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        recycler_view_list.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
    override fun onItemRangeInserted(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        recycler_view_list.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
    override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
        recycler_view_list.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
    override fun onItemRangeChanged(positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int, payload: Any?) {
        recycler_view_list.scrollToPosition(0)
    }
})

viewModel.myLiveData.observe { this, Observer { myList -> 
        adapter.submitList(myList) 
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks! But I had to skip the first call of `onItemRangeInserted()` to avoid losing scroll position on rotation.

Comment: This is genius man Thanks .Is there any better solution like optimized one to do the same .

Comment: This worked better than the other solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Use this way

```
viewModel.myLiveData.observe { this, Observer { myList -> 
    adapter.submitList(myList) // Assuming you are notifying adapter by notifydatasetchanged()
    recyclerView.post { recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) }
}
```

Here `post` is giving UI Thread some time to populate Recycler with new data and then call `scrollToPosition`.

Comment: _some time_ -> the post is telling android, add this work to the UI thread work queue. It's not "giving it some time" that is just a side-effect of you posting the work on a list that is already doing things. That's why it may work like this, but be careful, if the data is long or the diff util of the submit list takes longer, this is not going to always behave as you expect.

Comment: Perfect! Worked out for me.

Comment: This is not the solution as it sometimes works and other times it doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another option if you are looking to add a smoothscroll.

The ListAdapter class has a commit callback (Runnable) which will delay the post.

```
public void submitList(@Nullable List<T> list, @Nullable final Runnable commitCallback) {
    mDiffer.submitList(list, commitCallback);
}
```

This is how I update my list and smoothscroll to a position

```
viewModel.list.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
    adapter.submitList(it) {
        recycler.post { recyclerJobs.smoothScrollToPosition(0) }
    }
})
```

Comment: what is recyclerJobs?

Comment: Is it necessary to use `.post` as well as the `commitCallback`? Seems unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);

viewModel.myLiveData.observe { this, Observer { myList -> 
        adapter.submitList(myList) 
         recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for response. But the only work that did worked for me was to place a 1 second delay after executing submitList. Even though not appropriate one, But works for the following reason:

`adapter.submitList()` will always take the same execution time (within milliseconds)

I just called

```
Handler().postDelayed ({
  recycler.scrollToPosition(0)
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Instead of One second delay     recyclerView.post { recyclerView.scrollToPosition(0) } this will be better. You can try this. Also this will not create Handler() each time your data update. It will queue scroll task to same queue RecyclerView using for it's update. Check My answer, This way you will be saving a small amount of memory(To save each Handler created) and Computation(Creating Handler Object) also nearly no visible delay on scrolling.

Comment: Don't forgot to accept and upvote answer if it helps.