# Why submitList function of ListAdapter is not working?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I'm pretty sure that my list has changed but the view not updated
I'm using `submitList` like this:

```kotlin
recentChatsAdapter.submitList(recentChats?.let { ArrayList<Conversation>(it) })
```

DiffUtil code:

```kotlin
class ChatDiffUtil: DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Conversation>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Conversation, newItem: Conversation): Boolean {
        return oldItem.chatId == newItem.chatId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Conversation, newItem: Conversation): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49726385/listadapter-not-updating-item-in-recyclerview) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55263384/listadapter-not-refreshing-recyclerview-if-i-submit-the-same-list-with-different)

but I didn't find any solution to my problem.

Comment: Post your code of `DiffUtil` class.

Comment: Ok, I added `DiffUtil` class to question

Comment: Try to Log something in those two methods to see if it works well.

Comment: they are working well, I'm sure about that